# ClientDependency Framework & Razor, add custom JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, client-dependency

I'm trying to get the hang of ClientDependency Framework.
https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency
I use it in an Umbraco website.

I'm having a problem with some custom javascript (not in a file) that I want to run.

I want to run a function (which is in "functions.js"), but with a different parameter per page.

So, I add the following to my template:

```
Html.RequireJs("~/scripts/functions.js", 1);
```

And on my masterpage before the -tag I've added:

```
@Html.RenderJsHere()
```

But where do I place my function-call? I can't just add it to my template, because "functions.js" isn't loaded yet (it's at the bottom of my masterpage).

I've thought about creating a js-file for each call and add them to the Html.RequireJs(...) but that isn't a great solution.

Is there a way to add inline-script to the list of "JS-to-render" ?

edit:
I was just trying to get it to work using RenderSection(), but that doesn't seem to work when the section is defined on a macro?

edit:
I don't have the code here at the moment I'm typing this, but the idea is like this:

**functions.js**

```
function WriteToConsole(input) {
    console.log('Log', input);
}
```

**template1.cshtml**

```
@{Html.RequireJs("functions.js");}
<script>
    WriteToConsole("This is from template 1");
</script>
```

**template2.cshtml**

```
@{Html.RequireJs("functions.js");}
<script>
    WriteToConsole("This is from template 2");
</script>
```

**master.cshtml**

```
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Html.RenderJsHere()
</body>
```

Just to give an idea of what I'm trying to do.
As you can imagine, the `<script>` part on my template is now being called before `functions.js` is included. And this results in an error.

Or am I handling this whole thing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to alter the script call in: `Html.RequireJs("~/scripts/functions.js", 1);` ?

So something like `Html.RequireJs("~/scripts/functions.js?myparam=xyz", 1);` Is this what you are trying to achieve but having the url be dynamic?

If so you could do something like this :

```
//perhaps have some logic above to determine what the query should be and concatenate it to the string like so.
string query = "?myparam=xyz";
string scriptcall = "~/scripts/functions.js"+query ;
Html.RequireJs(scriptcall, 1);
```

Could you provide more code so we can see what you are trying to do? Maybe list in steps on how it should work?